# Amazon EC2 can pause?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I test my app with EC2 free trial proposal ,  I create several instances but want keep in free , so I want to pause some server and  start when use one day.

what I need is choose stop? which instance will be recycled during stopping?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can Stop the instance to use in future. 
You can only stop EBS based instance.

Comment: I see my free instance's volume under EBS in EC2 Management Console.in a words, if  action menu has the item "stop",which means I can stop and EC2 system can't recycle it?

Comment: I an not able to understand your comment. You want to stop your instance to use in future right? If those are EBS based instances then yes you can stop them and Start them in future. When you will start them you will get them as it's current state. You will not billed for your stopped instances.